# Create a "read-only" file system, that can still update packages

Tags: raspbian, readonly, overlayfs

I would like to configure my system (raspbian) in a way that it is read-only most of the time. I have a script that runs every few days/weeks that updates all the important installed packages so I stay up to date.

I've read that I just have to add the lines

```
tmpfs   /tmp            tmpfs   nodev,nosuid 0 0
tmpfs   /var/log        tmpfs   nodev,nosuid 0 0
tmpfs   /var/tmp        tmpfs   nodev,nosuid 0 0
tmpfs   /var/cache      tmpfs   nodev,nosuid 0 0
tmpfs   /home/pi/.cache     tmpfs   nodev,nosuid 0 0
# maybe some other dirs as well?
```

to `/etc/fstab` and that I have to set the default of `/` and `/boot` to `ro` as well.

I've also read that I just have to run the commands

```
$ sudo -o remount,rw /
$ sudo -o remount,rw /boot
```

to be able to update and run the same command but with `ro` instead of `rw` to enable read-only again.

I also read something about using overlayFS but is this necessary or advised? Or are the mentioned steps enough to achieve my goal?

Comment: Playing with mount option and changing `ro` to `rw` and vice versa sounds about right. But why do you want to set FS to a read-only mode in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

"Readonly" and "Need updates" are controversial requirements for system.
Readonly fs (root) - is linux-box attribute for production. Less opportunities for unwanted side interference. More garanty of stablility.

Updates is needable if linux-box distro is under construction.

Common practice - keep development platform root in RW, then, on release freeze it to RO and solve pack of problems with it (some services/application are absolutly not ready for RO, especially python modules).

But, if your system is so special. I think, you need think twice about RO-area end RW-area. Linux mount system is very flexible. You can manage every entry of /usr/lib/ or something. Make a strict map of freezed distro = RO-area, and updatable distro - RW-area. Make double checking of updatable content. Make some procedures to avoid hacking. No root accounts, no leaky access protocols, so on.